# Cannot connect to my laravel site in my CentOS

Tags: laravel, installation, centos, composer-php

I just installed laravel in my centOS following [this guide](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-laravel-on-centos-7/). When I try to get in it just says "403 Forbidden". However other applications run just fine. I have also checked the permissions.

This works:

```
myserverip/myproject/mypage.php
```

This works too:

```
myserverip/mylaravelproject/random_page_that_doesnt_have_anything_to_do_with_laravel.php
```

This is forbidden:

```
myserverip/mylaravelproject/
```

Since other pages work even in the laravel directory I assume I am missing something from laravel and not server-side.

Comment: Id suggest using a more updated version of laravel to start with. Especially if you're developing a new project

Comment: @scottevans93 I replaced that command to get the latest version (5.3.26)

Comment: What the difference between `/myproject/` & `/mylaravelproject/`?

Comment: @scottevans93 myproject is a random folder. Mylaravelproject is the folder where the laravel site is and was created with the laravel command.

Comment: Try `myserverip/mylaravelproject/public`

Comment: @scottevans93 It worked! thanks!

Comment: Glad to help, ive created an answer. Could you accept it for future viewers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `myserverip/mylaravelproject/public`

the `public` folder is where the base laravel stack begins

Answer (score 0):

**I'm not sure but may be this case**
URL   `myserverip/myproject/mypage.php` work means laravel working fine. So may be the problem with laravel trying to attempt prohibited folder `mylaravelproject`.

First try to confirm that `mylaravelproject` not into your laravel system because this cause 403. If you found that directory then remove it and check for same.

Answer (score 0):

Give your `storage` folder write permission. Hope it will solve your problem